# Blazor - HTML hierarchy issue. Child Razor components restricted by their parents CSS style rules

Tags: html, css, razor, blazor

I am having issues working with Razor components that I would otherwise solve by putting elements higher in the HTML document tree with fixed positioning.

For instance here I use context menu and tooltip components and they are unable to appear above the transparent sibling of their parent to the right.

[image: Context Menu] [image: Tooltip]

In HTML if you have an element inside another element, your child element is subject to the CSS styles of its parent elements. This particularly applies to elements that would escape the bounds of their parents and appear above their parents and their parents siblings. Such as Menus, Modals, Dialogs and Tooltips.

For instance, here is a simple HTML structure where a dialog could be opened by a sidebar or on the main page area. Despite being fixed in position the NavBar dialog (Dialog A) cannot overlap the main area.

```html
<div style='display: flex;'>
    <div style='position: relative; background-color: aqua; width: 200px; position: sticky; top: 0; display: inline-block;'>
      NavBar
      <div style='position: fixed; width: 400px; background-color: green; left: 0; top: 50px;'>Dialog A</div>
    </div>
    <div style='position: relative; background-color: red; display: flex; height: 200px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;'>
      Main
      <div style='position: fixed; width: 400px; background-color: yellow; left: 0; top: 100px;'>Dialog B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example Dialog B can overlap both the NavBar and the Main, but Dialog A cannot.
If you increase the z-index of the Sidebar, the inverse happens and Dialog A overlaps both, but Dialog B cannot.
I would usually solve this by moving the dialogs into a container that is higher in the tree.

```html
<div style='display: flex;'>
    <div style='position: relative; background-color: aqua; width: 200px; position: sticky; top: 0; display: inline-block;'>
        NavBar
    </div>
    <div style='position: relative; background-color: red; display: flex; height: 200px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;'>
        Main
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style='position: fixed; width: 400px; background-color: green; left: 0; top: 50px;'>Dialog A</div>
        <div style='position: fixed; width: 400px; background-color: yellow; left: 0; top: 100px;'>Dialog B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this is not obviously done in Blazor. For a component such as a NavBar to show a dialog, that dialog would be a child component inside the NavBar.

i.e. the NavBar code might look like this.

```
<button onclick="@OpenTheDialog">Open Dialog</button>
<MyDialog @bind-Visible='DialogVisible'>
    <div @onclick="Rename">Delete</div>
    <div @onclick="Delete">Delete</div>
</MyDialog>
void OpenTheDialog() 
    { 
        DialogVisible = true; 
    }  
private bool DialogVisible { get; set; }
```

Three solutions come to mind, each with flaws. Are there any other and better ways to deal with these situations?

Firstly, at a CSS level (in the example I gave) I could remove the relative positioning of the Main and NavBar. However, these are useful and important CSS styles and working around them is problematic. Other CSS styles also cause similar problems. For instance, if you take "position: relative" off of the Main element on the example and add "filter: blur(1px);" dialog B cannot escape the Main and dialog A cannot overlap the Main.

Secondly, I could use JavaScript Interop to move the dialog elements in the HTML document tree. Blazor does not play well with this as it does not track the change in the DOM which leads to issues.

Finally, I can use a cascading parameter to send a message higher up the Blazor component tree that a dialog should be opened. This could even be a component type to use for the dialog.

```
[CascadingParameter] public IDialogOpener DialogOpener { get; set; }
DialogOpener.Show<MyDialog>();
```

I feel this is the best option. However, it does not let you define the child component structure using Razor inside of the component that is opening the dialog and does not facilitate useful Razor features like double binding. You could pass in parameters to the dialog but getting back changes to those parameters would likely require separate callback change events also passed as parameters.

What is the best way to modify components to achieve this in Blazor?

Comment: Tried using the <dialog /> element?

Comment: https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorDialogs This is a demo app and lib that wraps the dialog element.

Comment: @BrianParker Thanks for the quick response Brian, just tried replacing the div for Dialog A with <dialog open> and it wasn't able to overlap the Main in the example so html dialog elements are not immune to their ancestors styles.
I will give that GitHub package a go shortly.

Comment: Yes it needs a little JS to open it properly its covered in its docs. The library wraps the required JS.

Comment: As a test I put `style="overflow:hidden;"` on the demo apps `div` on the `index` page and it ignored it.

Comment: [Polite] I'm not quite sure exactly what your question is.  Take a look at the various (free) Dialog implementations out there.  The dialog is implemented in `App` and thus at the top of the tree.  Most provide a dialog wrapper to a component.  There's a relatively simple one of mine!  Don't wait on a MS Blazor one, I'm pretty sure it won't be coming

Comment: Thank you both. @Brian Your solution does partly solve my issue, thank you!
It solves the issue for modal dialogs but unfortunately not for non-modals.
The ShowModal() call lets the dialog escape the overlapping rules but the Show() call doesn't.
I am not looking for a specific component I have used many different component from sources like github and telerik that have this issue. I am looking for a Blazor, CSS or HTML feature I can use that is a better solution than the three approaches I listed.
I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear enough I have edited it to hopefully add more clarity.